# Ipad Mini 2 wont work with SOAP webservice [XAMARIN.IOS]

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I need help, Im trying to call a SOAP web service to send an UIImage bytes to a database in the server, the problem here is that when I use an Ipad Mini 2 the web service doesn't work, and the image bytes never go to the server, the strange thing is that it works smoothly in an Iphone 4, Iphone 5, Iphone 6 and an Ipad Mini, but not in the Mini 2, anyone has an idea of why this is happening?

Comment: the form factor should not matter.  The iOS version might - is the broken one a different version than the others?  Further, have you done anything to actually debug the problem?  Add in logging, or use the debugger to catch any exceptions or errors that occur?

Comment: No idea what would the be cause :) , but you could try and send base64 string rather than a byte array

Comment: ugh do not do base64 strings for images unless you are doing CSS image embedding for catching.